# instanceof check on dynamic type

Tags: c#, xamarin

I have the following:

```
interface IViewable {}

class Node {}

class DecisionNode : Node, IViewable {}
```

In one segment of the application, I have the following method, to which I pass an instance of DecisionNode:

```
void handleNode (Node node)
{
    // ...
    var viewable = node as IViewable;
    // ...
}
```

The problem is that this does not seem to check whether or not the dynamic/runtime type of `node` is actually a subclass of `IViewable`. It correctly rules out that this holds for the static type (`Node`), but this is not what I want to check. I get the same result if I try to cast or use `is`.

I have been advised to use `GetType ().IsAssignableFrom()` in order to solve this, but the platform I am using (Xamarin) does not allow this.

Is there any other way I can check if the dynamic type of my object can be treated as an instance of a given type?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`as` *does* do a type-check; it simply returns `null` if the check fails, which you can test with `if`:

```
if(viewable != null) {
      ...
} else {
      ...
}
```

Re:

> `node` cannot be treated as an instance of `IViewable`

That is correct; however, `viewable` *can be*; simply run the `IViewable`-related code against `viewable`.

If you want to **assert** that this conversion should always work; just cast:

```
var viewable = (IViewable)node;
```

---

As an example, the following outputs:

```
DecisionNode: True
Node: False
```

code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var prog = new Program();
        prog.handleNode(new DecisionNode());
        prog.handleNode(new Node());
    }
    void handleNode(Node node)
    {
        var viewable = node as IViewable;
        System.Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}",
            node.GetType().Name,
            viewable != null);
    }
}
interface IViewable { }
class Node { }
class DecisionNode : Node, IViewable { }
```

---

If you can't get it to work, consider:

```
// play hunt the interface
if(viewable == null) {
    foreach(Type iType in node.GetType().GetInterfaces()) {
        if(iType.Name == "IViewable") {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} vs {1}",
                iType.AssemblyQualifiedName,
                typeof(IViewable).AssemblyQualifiedName);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I understand that, but the problem is not whether or not `as` does a typecheck, but rather *how* I can typecheck based on the dynamic type of the object, as it seems `as` only does so based on the static type. I know that node in this case is an instance of `DecisionNode`, and hence also an instance of `IViewable`, but the typecheck does not bear this out.

Comment: @chrsva no, `is` and `as` operate against the runtime type, not the static type. I'm deliberately not using the term "dynamic type", because that gets confusing with `dynamic` etc, which is unrelated. If your type-check is not working correctly, then I suspect the actual problem is something else - probably a duplicate interface declaration.

Comment: Odd, there are no duplicate declarations from what I can tell. I will check the rest of the build and try to figure out what is going wrong.

Comment: @chrsva I added a "play hunt the interface" snippet to the bottom of the post; you could add that (temporarily) to your `handleNode` method, and see what comes out. You might need to replace `Console.WriteLine` with a platform-specific alternative, note.

Comment: I tracked down the problem. We generate some of our object graphs by deserializing JSON, and as it turns out some of the nodes were improperly type annotated. Fixing that also solves the problem, which as it turned out was formulated on false premises. I am accepting your answer since it does answer the question as formulated, and has some good useful stuff to go with it. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

`as` does do a type check.

The [`as`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cscsdfbt.aspx) keyword does some sort of 'soft' casting, it tries, and if it fails, it reverts to `null`:

> The as operator is like a cast operation. However, if the conversion isn't possible, as returns null instead of raising an exception.

So check for `null` and you will know if `viewable` is `null` or not the requested type:

```
var viewable = node as IViewable;
if (viewable != null)
{
    // go ahead!
}
```

Or check using `is`:

```
if (node is IViewable)
{
    var viewable = (IViewable)node; // this is safe now
    // go ahead!
}
```

Comment: Note that the first approach (the null check) is recommended for performance. And in C# 6 we can write `if ((var viewable = node as IViewable) != null) { ... }`

Comment: @Bas interestingly, it is not trivial to choose between `is`+cast versus `as`+null-check; there are plenty of scenarios where each is faster. In most everyday uses, *it won't matter*